# Select records with most current log

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to pull off this query without running an inner query, but can't seem to get the records correctly.

I have two tables (naming convention changed for readability) ...

```
report
    report_id
    name

report_status_log
   report_id
   code
   timestamp
```

A report can have several status logs. I'm trying to get all reports where the most current report_status_log is equal to a certain code.

This won't work...

```
select report.id
       inner join report_status_log on report.report_id = report_status_log.report_id
where  report_status_log.code = 'finished'
```

... because although 'finished' might be in the status logs, it isn't necessarily always the latest log record.

Is there a way to do this? Or should I be selecting from report_status_log table instead of the report table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with cte as (
  select *, 
    row_number() over (partition by report_id order by timestamp desc) as RowNum
  from report_status_log
)

select * 
from report r
inner join cte c
on r.report_id = c.report_id
where c.code = 'finished' and RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just use the max function on the timestamp to get the most recent log?

```
select report_id
from report
inner join report_status_log on report.report_id = report_status_log.report_id
where timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM report_status_log)
and report_status_log.code = 'finished'
```

Comment: Yes, this question is exceptionally common on StackOverflow. This is the second one today. Certainly this is the most logical and direct method.

Comment: This worked but would only get a single record, not 100% sure why